# CSS is not loading in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter

http://dev.example.co.uk/dashboard/login

When I open URL then page and content load perfectly but the css and js is not loading.
The CSS is coming from MY_Controller.php

```
$this->css_files[] = array(
   'filename'=>'/css/default.css',
   'media'=>'screen',
   'rel'=>'stylesheet'
);`
```

I loaded in header and when open my website then the path is also correct http://dev.example.co.uk/css/default.css?v=1488798796
But when I open then I got 404 error.

I guess the URL treat like controller(css) and method(default.css).

Is the problem?

Comment: check css and js file path

Comment: $autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: Yes, already added.

Comment: <link href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: above code example to include css files in codeigniter

Comment: Hello @BilalAhmed I made functionality for add CSS and JS from MY_Controller.php

Comment: you have to tell your apache (or whatever) that the requests to `/css` don't go the CI `index.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed code of .htaccess file
and add new code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and worked great.

Comment: If it worked for you, please mark your answer as correct for future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache and you are using friendly urls you have to exclude `/css` folder in the rewrite condition. i.e:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|img|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

All the requests except those mapped in the 2nd line will be handled by `CI`

Answer (score 0):

I think ,your problem is `$config['base_url']` in `application/config/config.php`

you can set address to locate site.for example

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost:8085/hamed_hossani_site_path';
```